# How to include the title of the website in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I want to include the website title in my bibliography. In the bibtex file (created by Zotero) the website title is stored as `journal`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{test1,
    address = {London},
    url = {www.jstor.com/somearticle.html},
    urldate = {2013-10-29},
    title = {Cyberprotest: {New} media, citizens, and social movements},
    publisher = {Routledge},
    editor = {van de Donk, Wim B. H. J.},
    year = {2004}
}
@misc{test2,
    title = {This is the title of the webpage},
    url = {www.blog.com},
    urldate = {2013-08-29},
    journal = {This is the title of the website},
    month = feb,
    year = {2009}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

% Remove series & month
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearfield{series}
  \clearfield{labelmonth}
  \clearfield{edition}
}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test1} 

\cite{test2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Just a note, if you do not use any of `xpatch`'s commands (`\xpatch...`, `\xappto..` and the like; you do not seem to use it in this MWE, but I cannot be not sure about your actual document), there is no point in loading it.

Comment: Now to your problem: This is clearly a misuse of the `journal` entry by Zotero, and as such should probably be dealt with at a Zotero-level (i.e. make sure that the entry is not exported in this particular manner; I'm sure there are a lot of options to control exporting to `.bib` files). This issue brings to light another problem though: Neither `@misc` nor `@online` (I would have argued that `@online` is the more appropriate entry type here) support the `maintitle` field or anything else that would work as the "website title".

Comment: A work-around would be to put the website title into `title` and the page title into `subtitle` (this will yield unsatisfying in-text citations though). Or you could use the `titleaddon` field for the website name. A last option is to not display the  website title at all, also a viable option (in the few cases I had to cite actual webpages [make sure there is not floating around another document you could cite, a journal article or a techreport or the like], most of them did not have a website title that was worthwhile to be included).

Comment: @moewe  Actually I need to cite an article of the online Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (here the link to their citation instructions: http://plato.stanford.edu/cite.html). The the title of the website seems quite relevant.

Comment: Well in that case `@inreference` comes to mind.

Comment: The website actually suggests `@incollection` (see [Author and Citation Information for "Classical Logic"](http://plato.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/encyclopedia/archinfo.cgi?entry=logic-classical)), `@inreference` is actually just a special alias for `@incollection`, the `biblatex` standard styles treat both types the same (AFAIK).

Comment: Are you still interested in a proper answer? Or would my comment above suffice as an answer?

Comment: @moewe Your comments helped me and I probably would leave them as a comments since the main point is quite simply that `@misc` doesn't allow for a `maintitle` field.

Answer (score 5):

We can add support for the `maintitle` field in `@online` and `@misc` using the amazing [`xpatch` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) as easily as

```
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\usebibmacro{title}}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\usebibmacro{title}}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle}}
  {}{}
```

This will add the `maintitle` after the `title`.

---

In your special case though since you want to cite the SEP, you should probably go with the suggestions on their website (see [Author and Citation Information for "Classical Logic"](http://plato.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/encyclopedia/archinfo.cgi?entry=logic-classical) for example): use `@incollection`.

```
@incollection{sep-set-theory,
  author       = {Jech, Thomas},
  title        = {Set Theory},
  booktitle    = {The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
  editor       = {Edward N. Zalta},
  url          = {http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/win2011/entries/set-theory/},
  urldate      = {2014-04-23},
  year         = {2011},
  edition      = {Winter 2011},
}
```

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{cybeprotest,
  editor    = {van de Donk, Wim and Brian D. Loader and Paul G. Nixon and Dieter Rucht},
  title     = {Cyberprotest},
  subtitle  = {New Media, Citizens and Social Movements},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  address   = {location},
  date      = {2004},
  url       = {www.jstor.com/somearticle.html},
  urldate   = {2013-10-29},
  isbn      = {978-0-415-29784-4},
}
@online{web,
  title     = {This is the title of the webpage},
  maintitle = {This is the title of the website},
  date      = {2009-02},
  url       = {http://www.example.com},
  urldate   = {2013-08-29},
}
@incollection{sep-set-theory,
  author       = {Jech, Thomas},
  title        = {Set Theory},
  booktitle    = {The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
  editor       = {Edward N. Zalta},
  url          = {http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/win2011/entries/set-theory/},
  urldate      = {2014-04-23},
  year         = {2011},
  edition      = {Winter 2011},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearfield{series}
  \clearfield{labelmonth}
  \clearfield{edition}
}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\usepackage[british]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\usebibmacro{title}}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\usebibmacro{title}}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle}}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]