# Show institution with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like the institution to be shown in the bibliography in italics. How do I have to change my code in order to achieve that?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @Electronic{musk,
        author      = {Elon Musk},
        title       = {Tesla Model X},
        url         = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
        date        = {2017-07-04},
        institution = {Tesla},
        urldate     = {2018-10-16}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Let's cite! \footcite{musk}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@online` entry type does not use the field `institution`, but it knows the similar field `organization` (most types know at least one of `institution`, `organization` and `publisher`, some types support `publisher` and `organization`). You can find the list of known fields for each entry type in section 2.1 *Entry Types* of [the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

By default `organization` is printed without special formatting (just like `institution` and `publisher`), if you want to print it in italics (emphasised), you can use `\DeclareListWrapperFormat` if you use the `biblatex` 3.12 or above.

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{musk,
  author       = {Elon Musk},
  title        = {Tesla Model X},
  url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
  date         = {2017-07-04},
  organization = {Tesla},
  urldate      = {2018-10-16},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareListWrapperFormat{organization}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! \footcite{musk}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Musk, Elon. Tesla Model X. Tesla. July 4, 2017. url: https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no (visited on 10/16/2018).]

---

If you are using a `biblatex` version older than 3.12, where `\DeclareListWrapperFormat` is not yet available you can use

```
\DeclareListFormat{organization}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  \mkbibemph{#1}\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}
```

In case you are using an exporter that stubbornly insist on using `institution` instead of `organization` you can let Biber remap the fields

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{online}
      \pertype{electronic}
      \step[fieldsource=institution]
      \step[fieldset=organization, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you don't want to show the organization/institution of the website, and are more interested in the 'overall title' of the website, you may want to try `maintitle`, but that would have to be patched into the driver first, see [How to include the title of the website in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172441/35864).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just noticed that the organization appears after the title. How do I have to change that. I didn't find a question that already exists, which I find hard to believe, but sometimes it's difficult to find a question if you don't know the technical terms. So if there's a similar question I would be glad if you could post the link.

Comment: @derd Where would you want to see the `organization` instead? Between `author` and `title`? I'm not sure there is a question for that already. I suggest you ask a new question about that. But it might be easier to try a work-around here. On the other hand "Musk, Elon. *Tesla.* *Tesla Model X.*" looks a bit like the house style of the department of redundancy department.