# Show website title in biblatex bibliography for @online entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, titles, online

I want to display the website title in my bibliography. 
Currently it looks like this:
[image]

The website title should be between the year and the url.
I use Zotero for my bib management and it files the website title under journal title.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @online{eosmed2013,
    title = {Additive Fertigungsverfahren in der Medizin},
    author = {{N. N.}},
    date = {2013},
    journaltitle = {https://www.eos.info/},
    url = {https://cdn0.scrvt.com/eos/public/66918c41e39c1b11/d05335391d6a4957d64dc29be4905963/medizinbroschuere.pdf},
    urldate = {2020-02-27}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ext-numeric,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    sorting=nyt,
    autocite=inline,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    articlein=false,
    innamebeforetitle=true,
    giveninits=true,
    maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}


\begin{document}
    \cite{eosmed2013}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: And what is this website title?

Comment: it's "https://www.eos.info/", Zotero puts it in the field "journaltitle"

Comment: There no field for the website title in the standard `biblatex` data model. `journaltitle` certainly is not the right field here. You can look into using `maintitle` for that, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457593/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172441/35864

Comment: The second approach would work, but I would have to manually change the field 'journaltitle' to 'maintitle' for every @online entry everytime Zotero export the .bib file

Comment: Then tell Zotero to export the website title into `maintitle` instead of `journaltitle` (which is most definitely useless anyway). If there is no option in vanilla Zotero I'm sure you can cook up something with https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/ (I have never used Zotero nor Zotero Better BibTeX myself, so this is just hearsay).